# HATEOAS and dynamic discovery of API

Tags: java, rest, restful-url, restful-architecture, hateoas

The HATEOAS principle "Clients make state transitions only through actions that are dynamically identified within hypermedia by the server"

Now I have a problem with the word dynamically, though I guess it's the single most important word there.

If I change one of my parameters from say optional to mandatory in the API, I **HAVE** to fix my client else the request would fail.

In short, all HATEOAS does is give the server side developer extreme liberty to change the API at will, at the cost of all clients using his/her API.

Am I right in saying this, or am I missing something like versioning or maybe some other media-type than JSON which the server has to adopt?

Answer (score 2):

Any time you change a parameter from optional to mandatory in an API, you *will* break consumers of that API. That it is a REST API that follows HATEOAS principles does not change this in any way. Instead, if you wish to maintain compatibility you should avoid making such changes; ensure that any call made or message sent by a client written against the old API will continue to function as expected.

On the other hand, it is also a good idea to not write clients to expect the set of returned elements to always be identical. They should be able to ignore additional information given by a server if the server chooses to provide it. Again, this is just good API design.

HATEOAS isn't the problem. Excessively rigid API expectations are the problem. HATEOAS is just *part* of the solution to the problem (as it potentially relieves clients from having to know vast amounts about the state model of the service, even if it doesn't necessarily make it straight-forward).

Answer (score 1):

Donal Fellows has a good answer, but there's another side to the same coin. The HATEOAS principle doesn't have anything to say itself about the format of your messages (other parts of REST do); instead, it means essentially that the client should not try to know which URI's to act upon out of band. Instead, the server should tell the client which URI's are of interest via hyperlinks (or forms/templates which construct hyperlinks). How it works:

1. The client starts at state 0.
2. The client requests a well-known resource.
3. The server's response moves the client to a new state *N*. There may be multiple states achievable at this point depending on the response code and payload.
4. The response includes links (or forms/templates) which tell the client, *in band*, the set of potential next states.
5. The client selects one of the potential next states by issuing a method on a URI.

Repeat 3 through 5 to states *N+1* and beyond until the client's application needs are met.

In this fashion, the server is free to change the URI that moves the client from state *N* to state *N+1* without breaking the client.

Comment: This would suggest extensive code at client side, say the client is a frontend  App. Should this level of complexity be introduced there? For example, Perform a set of operations(on UI) if resource/A is found, or entirely different set, if resource/A is not found.

I still do not have full grasp of this concept

Comment: @DipanshuVerma It is questionable if a frontent client to a web API has to follow RESTful guidelines or not. REST's intention are basically the decoupling of clients from API/web services in a distributed system. I don't think that if both webshop and some arbitrary API are developed by the same team REST is really the way to go as usually both are maintained simulatenously and thus a changes from the API will reflect in the change of the webshop accordingly. REST should be applied though if there are plenty of clients using that web API where the client might not be under your direct control

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you misunderstood the quoted principle. Your question suggests that you think about the resources and that they could be "dynamically" defined. Like a mandatory property added to certain resource type at the application runtime. This is *not* what the principle says and this was correctly pointed out in other answers. The quoted principle says that the **actions within the hypermedia should be dynamically identified**.

The actions available for a given resource may change in time (e.g. because someone added/removed a relationship in the meantime) and there may be different actions available for the same resource but for different users (e.g. because users have different authorization levels). The idea of HATEOAS is that clients should not have any assumptions about actions available for certain resource at any given time. **The client should identify available actions each time it reads that resource**.

Edit: The below paragraph may be wrong. See the comments for discussion about it.

On the other hand clients may have expectation for the data available in the resource. Like that a `book` resource must have a `title` and that it there *may* be links to the book's author or authors. There is no way of avoiding the coupling introduced by these assumptions but both service providers and clients should use backward-compatibility and versioning techniques to deal with it.

Comment: Actually your last paragraph refers to ["typed" resources](http://soabits.blogspot.co.at/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html) which Fielding mentioned that [`A REST API should never have "typed" resources that are significant to the client`](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven) as this couples clients tightly to APIs, instead they should `spend its descriptive effort into creating media types used for representing resources and driving application state, or in defining extended relation names and hypertext-enabled mark-up`

Comment: @RomanVottner: I was not 100% sure myself when I wrote that last paragraph. After reading the articles that you linked I must say that it's still not totally clear to me. How is the client supposed to know that when following link named `author` it can request a media type, say, `application/vcard+xml`? [RFC8828](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8288) specifies that there may be `type` specified in the link but it also says that it's just a hint and there may be just _one_ media type specified that way. Is this the knowledge abut the domain model which must be coded in the client?

Comment: In HTTP the actual available operations that can be used on resources can be queried via `OPTIONS` while the actual media-type a representation of some resource should be returned for is [negotiated between client and server](http://restlet.com/company/blog/2015/12/10/understanding-http-content-negotiation/) via `Accept` and `Content-Type` HTTP headers. A media type itself is just a verbal description of how a user has to process certain data of that format and what its semantics are. Its implementation can be added dynamically into clients/servers using plugin or extension mechanisms i.e.

Comment: Media types may include instructions that a link given an `author` relation name should follow a media type representation of vCard (either [`text/vcard`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6350), [`application/vcard+xml`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6351) or [`application/vcard+json`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7095)). Fielding mentioned in his blog post that most descriptive effort should be put into creating media types and relation names or refining existing ones. Due to web browsers being examplary REST clients, you can always trace back how browsers are handling such things.